# How to make textures certain size and constant between objects?

Tags: texturing, materials

I've been using Blender for few months now and really really loving it otherwise but trying to understand how textures work in blender is making me want to give up. I mostly do just architectural stuff and I still don't understand how to set exact sizes for repeating textures (e.g. brick wall texture where I know the physical sizes) and how to get them stay the same size when used between different sized and shaped objects.

Most times I've just used Cube Projection and then have tried to adjust things by hand but it just seems like a lost cause.

Is there some simple way to achieve this or any plugins that could be used for this?

Comment: Hello :). Oh, this one's easy. Use UV maps and match the Texel Density for all your UVs. This addon should help: [Texel Density Checker addon on Gumroad](https://gumroad.com/l/CEIOR).

Comment: Some time ago I've given an answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184072/setting-image-texture-to-specific-size/184088#184088

Comment: Jachym I actually googled that one earlier but I did not spot any metric dimensions, only pixels so I got confused. I'll check that one out still.

@GordonBrinkmann Ah I actually tried your method too and I sort of got it working once for a simple flat plane but not with multiple objects with custom shapes.

I might have missed something crucial as with that method It made it so slow to mak materials and not being able to use node wrangler shortcuts or poliigon material converter anymore.

Comment: I guess you missed this section of my answer there ;) "The only problem is that - since the texture is not connected to any UVs or geometry of the new object - it will definitely not work well on curved objects and is only suitable for things like floors or walls or similar flat, even surfaces."

Comment: Coming back to this I tried your instructions again from the other question and it worked great! I think I messed up something the first time and also forgot to change all textures to box which caused stretching on some faces of the walls. Thank you for your help! I still really wish Blender would include a better inbuilt solution as this seems very manual compared to some other software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A texture with a texture coordinate node that is applied to different objects that have all had their scale applied should appear at the same scale across the .blend file. You can use the texture coordinate node to alter the texture to the right scale for your world.

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah I just have not figured out how to get the materials to exact sizes and set up the nodes that they would work straight to all objects. It's so weird that there is not a simple input to type in repeating texture dimensions in metric units.

Comment: But if you use a texture coordinate node (which includes scale), you would be able to adjust that across all the objects--as long as you're using the same instance of that texture on all those objects.